# How to inject two services on each other in emberjs?

Tags: ember.js

Suppose I have a two service X and Y. I want to use methods of both service in each other. If i inject service using intializer like this

```
application.inject('service:X', 'Y', 'service:Y');
application.inject('service:Y', 'X', 'service:X');
```

it will get an exception

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Any suggestion to do that it will be very helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use an initializer for that. Just simply inject the service to the other one like how you'd do it without using initializers.

```
// app/services/service-x.js
import Service from 'ember-service';
import service from 'ember-service/inject';

export default Service.extend({
  serviceY: service()
});

// app/services/service-y.js
import Service from 'ember-service';
import service from 'ember-service/inject';

export default Service.extend({
  serviceX: service()
});
```

Comment: Typically you don't want to statically import a service via `import` - instead, you want to use dependency injection so you have access to the service _instance_. Have a look at the [service guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/applications/services/)

Comment: @SamSelikoff - sorry, I'm not following what you're saying that you'll have access to the service instance. Did you mean the `this.get('serviceX')`?

Comment: This is perfectly ok. `ember-service/inject` is equivalent to `Ember.inject.server` I think. And this works because this does return a CP and so is lazy evaluated, in opposite to injecting with an initializer.

Comment: Lux is right, I've never seen this syntax before but it is the same as `Ember.inject.service()`